# Django - edit HTML table rows and update database

Tags: python, html, ajax, django, post

I created a HTML table, it contains some information. However I want to add the possibility to edit table row text and by clicking "save", the database would be updated.

Can someone help me?

Do I need to use Ajax? If so please can I get some guidance?

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Questions</th>
    <th>Answers</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  {% for q in questions%}
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable='true'>{{q.question}}</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>{{q.answer}}</td>
    <td>
      <center><a href="{% url 'edit_question' q.id %}">Save Edit --- </a><a href="{% url 'delete_question' q.id %}">Delete</a></center>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {%endfor%}
</table>
```

Here is my view, I know it shouldn't look like this because there is no parameter passed between the view and the HTML table, this needs to be fixed:

```
def edit_question(request,id):
  question = Question.objects.get(id=id)
  if(question):
    question.update(question = quest, answer = ans)
    return redirect('list_questions')
    return render(request, 'generator/questions.html', {'question': question})
```

**UPDATE**

I used the solution that @xxbinxx provided, However in the view function, the condition request.method == "POST" doesn't seem to be verified even if it's in ajax function ?

heres the updated code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveQuestionAnswer(e, id) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(id)
    editableQuestion = $('[data-id=question-' + id + ']')
    editableAnswer = $('[data-id=answer-' + id + ']') 
    console.log(editableQuestion.text(), editableAnswer.text())
    $.ajax({
        url: "list/update/"+id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "question": editableQuestion.html(), "answer": editableAnswer.html() },
        success: function(response) {
            // set updated value as old value 
            alert("Updated successfully")            
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("errr");
            alert("An error occurred")
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<table style="width:90%">
        <tr>
            <th ><font color="#db0011">Questions</th>
            <th><font color="#db0011">Answers</th>
            <th><font color="#db0011">Action</th>

        </tr>
        {% for q in questions%}
        <tr>
            <td width="40%" height="50px" contenteditable='true' data-id="question-{{q.id}}" data-old_value='{{q.question}}' onClick="highlightEdit(this);">{{q.question}}</td>
            <td width="45%" height="50px" contenteditable='true' data-id="answer-{{q.id}}" data-old_value='{{q.answer}}'>{{q.answer}}</td>
            <td width="15%" height="50px"><center>
        <a class="button" href="{% url 'edit_question' q.id %}" onclick="saveQuestionAnswer('{{q.id}}')">Edit</a>
        <a class="button" href="{% url 'delete_question' q.id %}">Delete</a>
      </center></td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    </table>
```

views.py

```
def edit_question(request,id):
    quest = Question.objects.get(id=id)
    print(quest)
    if request.method=='POST': # It doesn't access this condition so the updates won't occur
        print("*"*100)
        quest.question = request.POST.get('question')
        quest.answer = request.POST.get('answer')
        print(quest)
        quest.save()
        return redirect('list_questions')
    return render(request, 'browse/questions.html', {'quest': quest})
```

Can someone help me solve this final issue ?

Comment: yes you'll have to use `ajax` for in place editing.. Let me prepare an dummy HTML for you. You'll get the idea.

Comment: Check answer. Let me know if it's worth.

Comment: Ok thanks again, I'll do that right now

Comment: for updated question. comma "," is missing between `data` and `success` in code `data: {"question": editableQuestion.innerHTML, "answer": editableAnswer.innerHTML}
            success:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you'll have to use `AJAX` to achieve in-place editing. I'm posting quick code so you get the **idea**.

> NOTE: the below code has errors ;) I don't want to write in detail as it would be of no good to you. You must brainstorm and try it yourself.

- `contenteditable=”true”` is to make column editable.
- an attribute `data-old_value` to keep old value to check before making Ajax request to update changed value in your database table.
- Code is making use of function `saveQuestionAnswer()`
- on blur event to update changed value and function `highlightEdit()` to highlight column in edit mode.

```
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Questions</th>
        <th>Answers</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      {% for q in questions%}
      <tr>
        <td contenteditable='true' data-id="question-{{q.id}}" data-old_value='{{q.question}}' onClick="highlightEdit(this);">{{q.question}}</td>
        <td contenteditable='true' data-id="answer-{{q.id}}" data-old_value='{{q.answer}}' onClick="highlightEdit(this);">{{q.answer}}</td>
        <td>
          <center><a onclick="saveQuestionAnswer('{{q.id}}')">Save your edit --- </a><a href="{% url 'delete_question' q.id %}">Delete</a></center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {%endfor%}
    </table>

    <script>
    function saveQuestionAnswer(id) {

        editableQuestion = $('a[data-id=question-'+id+']') //this will get data-id=question-1 where 1 is the question ID
        editableAnswer = $('a[data-id=answer-'+id+']') //this will get data-id=answer-1 where 1 is the question ID

        // no change change made then return false
        if ($(editableQuestion).attr('data-old_value') === editableQuestion.innerHTML && $(editableAnswer).attr('data-old_value') === editableAnswer.innerHTML)
            return false;

        // send ajax to update value
        $(editableObj).css("background", "#FFF url(loader.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/my-save-url/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"question": editableQuestion.innerHTML, "answer": editableAnswer.innerHTML}
            success: function(response) {
                // set updated value as old value
                $(editableQuestion).attr('data-old_value', response.question);
                $(editableQuestion).css("background", "#FDFDFD");

                $(editableAnswer).attr('data-old_value', response.answer);
                $(editableAnswer).css("background", "#FDFDFD");
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("errr");
                alert("An error occurred")
            }
        });
    }

    function highlightEdit(elem){
      $(elem).css("background", "#e3e3e3") //just add any css or anything, it's only to depict that this area is being edited...
    }
    </script>
```

Your view will now get data in json format as `{'question': <value>, 'answer': <value>}`

you can add another key `'id'` in this `json` if you want, or you can keep your url like this `/saveQuestionAnswer/<id>`. Here you have your `id` in url itself.

I hope you understand now.

Thanks

Comment: @Oumab10 Did it helped??
what else are you looking for?

Comment: I have an issue with my view function, it doesn't seem to get the edited rows, plus I don't know what to fix in it, Im trying to figure it out ...

Comment: did you understood the JS part?

Comment: globally yes I got the idea ( I never used Javascript I'm new to web programming)

Comment: okay, you're doing well. Just try to use the code I gave you above. In your view you'll get the JSON data in `request.POST`. Try it, If you have any issues let us know but first make some efforts on your own.

Comment: Can you please help me solve this last issue, I can't seem to find the reason ... I added updates to the question

Comment: @Oumab10 I'll try. You should write **update** and then write your update to the question or better ask a new question (if the problem is something else) referencing this one. I forgot what we did last time and now I'm confused what's the update. lol

Comment: I wrote ** UPDATE ** above the updates that I inserted

Comment: @Oumab10 what does `print(request.method)` give to you?

Comment: it outputs "GET"

Comment: @Oumab10 can you check your network tab, what happens when you click to update. Check the request going is 'POST' or 'GET'. If it's 'GET' then your JS is the culprit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194101/discussion-between-xxbinxx-and-oumab10).