# how edit and delete rows from django_tables2 and make filter search in up of table and next and previous button

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-tables2

hello  my friends i use django_tables2 and i show my data table and all it is ok ... i want now to edit and remove rows and make filters search in up of table .. make next and pervious ... i do not find good documentation about this so can you help me ? this is the view code of my table showing in view
thank you

```
def Immoblist(request):
table = ImmobTable(Immob.objects.all())
table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=25)
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
return render(request,"immob_list.html", {'table': table})
#this is tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Immob
from django_tables2 import SingleTableView
from django_tables2.views import SingleTableMixin
class ImmobTable(tables.Table):
id = tables.Column(verbose_name= 'ID')
immo_code=tables.Column(verbose_name='Code')
immo_desig=tables.Column(verbose_name='Désignation')
immo_qte=tables.Column(verbose_name='Quantité ')
immo_datemes=tables.Column(verbose_name='Date  mes ')
immo_cptimmob=tables.Column(verbose_name='Compte comptable ')
immo_dureevie=tables.Column(verbose_name='Durée de vie ')
immo_origine=tables.Column(verbose_name='Origine ')
immo_fournisseur=tables.Column(verbose_name='Fournisseur ')
immo_nufact=tables.Column(verbose_name='N° facture ')
immo_datefact=tables.Column(verbose_name='Date facture ')
immo_valht=tables.Column(verbose_name='Valeur HT ')
immo_monaie=tables.Column(verbose_name='Monnaie ')
immo_tauxcvt=tables.Column(verbose_name='Taux de conversion ')
immo_tauxctrval=tables.Column(verbose_name='Contre valeur/DA ')
immo_frais=tables.Column(verbose_name="Frais d'approche ")
immo_coutacq=tables.Column(verbose_name="Cout total d'acquisition ")
immo_refcmde=tables.Column(verbose_name='Référence commande ')
immo_datecmde=tables.Column(verbose_name='Date commande ')
immo_journee=tables.Column(verbose_name='Numéro de journée ')
immo_cptanal=tables.Column(verbose_name='Compte Analytique')
immo_local=tables.Column(verbose_name='Localisation ')
immo_mode_amort=tables.Column(verbose_name="Méthode d'amortissement ")
immo_code_r=tables.Column(verbose_name="Dernier plan d'amortissement ")
immo_val_amort=tables.Column(verbose_name="Valeur à amortir ")
immo_status=tables.Column(verbose_name='Code status')
immo_code_bar=tables.Column(verbose_name='Code à barre ')
service=tables.Column(verbose_name='Service ')
cni=tables.Column(verbose_name='Code cni ')
class Meta:
    model = Immob
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-sm'}
    template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
class ImmobList(SingleTableView):
   model = Immob
   table_class = ImmobTable

#la page immob_list. HTML 
<!doctype html>
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load static%}
<html>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <head>
  <title>Liste des Immobilisations</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css'   %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="overflow-y: auto; height:10px; ">
            {% block content %}
              {% render_table table %}
              {% endblock content %}  
        </div>   
    </body>
   </table>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django_tables2 creates views through server side queries and doesn't have the ability to post data. Essentially, what it does is automate the creation of tables you can sort by column head.

From documentation:

"Features:

Any iterable can be a data-source, but special support for Django QuerySets is included.

The builtin UI does not rely on JavaScript.

Support for automatic table generation based on a Django model.

Supports custom column functionality via subclassing.

Pagination.

Column based table sorting.

Template tag to enable trivial rendering to HTML.

Generic view mixin."

Refer here to get an idea of how you can use JavaScript (Ajax) to be able to edit your data on the webpage. [Django - edit HTML table rows and update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56290703/django-edit-html-table-rows-and-update-database)