# Pass data form in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having a trouble on how can I pass data from `html` into `views.py` based on selected row button in my html and also I want to pass through `POST`.As you can see the trigger to pass data is through `Open` button which I've been using `href`.Is there any trick or idea how to pass dat using form etc.? It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

*This is similar for this problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56290703/14704233)*

[image]

*sample.Html*

```
  <div class="row">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for folder in folder_list %}
          Folder title: <span id="titles" name="titles" >{{folder.title}}</span></p>
          Date upload: <span  id="date_upload" name="date_upload">{{folder.date_upload}}</span>

          <a href="{% url 'view_gallery' %}" name="idd" value="{{ folder.id }}">Open</a>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

*views.py*

```
@login_required(login_url='log_permission')
def view_gallery(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       print("makibaoh")
       idd = request.POST.get('idd')
       title = request.POST.get('title')
       date_upload = request.POST.get('date_upload')
       image = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = idd)
       data = {'photos':image} 
       return render(request, 'view_gallery.html', data)
```

Comment: The html template is expecting to receive a list of items called `folder_list`, but the view is passing an item named `photos` instead.

Comment: @John Gordon Thanks for your response the folder_list works fine it comes from another def function. I just want to pass the current data of folder_list  to another def called `view_gallery`. The problem is how can I pass those data to view_galley def, need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any trick or idea how to pass data using form etc.?

If I understand correctly, you want to use `form` but `a` tag.

Try this:

```html
<div class="row">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for folder in folder_list %}
          Folder title: <span id="titles" name="titles" >{{folder.title}}</span></p>
          Date upload: <span  id="date_upload" name="date_upload">{{folder.date_upload}}</span>

          <form action="{% url 'view_gallery' %}" method="POST" id="form1">
               <!-- This input won't be show -->
               <input type="text" idd={{folder.id}} style="display:none"> 
               <button type="submit">Open</button>
          </form>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Then when you hit the `Open` button, a `POST` method will be made to url `view_gallery` with params `idd=123`. (*example.com/view_gallery?idd=123*)

Then it will work.

***But I strongly recommend you to organize URLs like this:***

- Declare <a> tag like:

```html
<a href="{% url 'view_detail_gallery' folder.id %}">
```

- Change your URL's pattern to something like: `example.com/view_gallery/:id`. Declare a new pattern URL:

```py
path('gallery/<int:id>/', view_detail_gallery, name = 'gallery_detail'),
```

- Declare a new view in `views.py`:

```py
@login_required(login_url='log_permission')
def view_detail_gallery(request, id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
       image = gallery_photos.objects.filter(gallery_info_id = id)
       data = {'photos':image} 
       return render(request, 'view_detail_gallery.html', data)
```

You can create a new `detail` HTML or not because as I can see, you didn't do it and your code is still working (Hope so).